# Logging to a file in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a Python program that will just log user input.

Here is the code:

```
import logging

# logging setup
logger = logging.getLogger("testapp")
hdlr = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(message)s")
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def main():
    userinput = input("> ")
    logger.debug(userinput)
    logger.info(userinput)
    logger.warning(userinput)
    logger.error(userinput)
    logger.critical(userinput)
    a = input("> ")  # wait for a newline before before closing

main()
```

When I run the code, the warning, error, and critical message get printed, like they should, but a file is not created and nothing is actually logged.

**Edit:** This error message shows up:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1025, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 869, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 611, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 580, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 422, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'level'
Call stack:
  File "C:/Users/matth/PycharmProjects/arb/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    logger.debug("Starting...")
Message: 'Starting...'
Arguments: ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a different object in your main function and in the rest of your code. You need to use the same logger object used above the function. For example:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('app')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s % 
(message)s")
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.error('Error logged')
```

Comment: To be clear, the `logging` module defines a root logger `logging.root`, and `logging.info` (for example) is basically a wrapper around `logging.root.info`. (The function also calls `basicConfig`, which adds a handler to `logging.root` if it doesn't already have one.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

The file 'example.log' will be created.